# Are Chinese symbols built from more elementary symbols or forms?

Tags: characters

I know nothing about the Chinese language but, while we ate in a Chinese restaurant with lots of Chinese symbols around me, I asked myself if these symbols could be built up from elementary lines or forms (like our words are made up out of 26 letters). Is that the case?

Answer (score 6):

explanation in modern day research:

we use components (部件), to "build up" chinese characters; and there're 1316.

http://chardb.iis.sinica.edu.tw/system_intro.jsp

basically, we have 8 types of stroke (筆畫) to compose each component.

about the "structural relations and configuration regularity" of components, have a look of this page; in english and traditional chinese:

http://other.allad.com.tw/chinese2/teacher_e.php

Comment: Any links to all the 1316 部件? Thanks

Comment: you may have a look of 漢語多功能字庫, for Oracle Bone Script Components: http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/oraclePiece.php
for Bronze Script Components: http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/bronzePiece.php

Comment: Unfortunately the number is far from the 1316. ='(    Any other source?

Comment: btw, the number is depends on who did the research (simplified, or traditional chinese, ). have a read of this pdf file:

http://cdp.sinica.edu.tw/service/documents/T090904.pdf

Answer (score 0):

仅仅从字形上划分有下面几类：The Chinese symbols can be built up from elementary lines or forms by following three types:

笔画：https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroke_(CJK_character)

偏旁：https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-tw/%E5%81%8F%E6%97%81

部首：https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_(Chinese_characters)

Answer (score 0):

A Chinese character is built-up by radical(部首) and character parts(偏旁). Here is a list of [radicals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Table_of_Indexing_Chinese_Character_Components), and here is a list with [examples](https://mszhaoschineseclass.weebly.com/uploads/9/7/9/6/9796141/names_of_radicals_and_character_parts.pdf?c=mkt_w_chnl:aff_geo:all_prtnr:sas_subprtnr:1538097_camp:brand_adtype:txtlnk_ag:weebly_lptype:hp_var:358504&sscid=71k6_mqmcm).